# How to split a data frame from an arrayBuffer with RxJS?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm using websocket to receive data frame from hardware.
The data frame is defined like this:

`0xbb(head) ---data--- 0xee(tail)`

the received data is store in Uint8Array, there maybe multiple frame:

```
var buffer = new Uint8Array([0xbb,0,0,0,0xee,0xbb,1,1,1,0xee,0xbb,3,3,3,0xee]);
```

and I can convert the array to observable:

`var obs= Rx.Observable.from(buffer);`

RxMarbles:

```
--0xbb--0--0--0--0xee--0xbb--1--1--1--0xee--0xbb--2--2--2--0xee------
------------------000------------------111------------------222------
```

How to use RxJS to split the observable? 
Which operators to use?
Is RxJS the best practice for this situation?

Comment: You mean you want to convert it to an array of `Observables`?

Comment: Yes, I want convert each data frame to an obsevable

Comment: @rhyttr What defines the number of items in each Observable?

Comment: Anyway it seems like you could use the `window()` operator or some of its variant: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-window

Comment: @martin The number of each data frame is variable. It's split by head(0xbb) and tail(0xee). I see the window(windowBoundaries: Observable<any>), but I don't know how to set the windowBoundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const source = Rx.Observable
  .from(['0xbb','0','0','0','0xee','0xbb','1','1','1','0xee','0xbb','3','3','3','0xee'])
  .concatMap(i => Rx.Observable.of(i).delay(1));

source
  .filter(i => i != '0xee' && i != '0xbb')
  .buffer(source.filter(i => i === '0xee'))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

We need to convert the values to async by using `concatMap(.. delay(1))` because otherwise the `closingNotifier` of buffer is running faster then the ingestion of values and you end up with three empty array's. But since you receive these packets from a websocket you are already async.

This code is not 100% foolproof, for instance what should happen when the external device does not emit `0xee`? We end up with the next message being concatenated to the previous message.

Comment: Thanks your answer, You reminded me that the byte buffer need convert to time streaming, so RxJS can operate. but did this delay concatMap(.. delay(1)) will have performance problem when fast and large amount
communication?

Comment: You could also use `observeOn(async)` instead of `delay(1)`. `async` comes from `import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';`

Answer (score 2):

I think you could achieve what you want with `scan()`:

```
const buffer = new Uint8Array([0xbb,0,0,0,0xee,0xbb,1,1,1,0xee,0xbb,3,3,3,0xee]);
const obs = Observable.from(buffer);

obs.scan((acc, v) => {
    if (v === 0xbb) {
      return [v];
    } else {
      acc.push(v);
      return acc;
    }
  }, [])
  .filter(acc => acc[acc.length - 1] === 0xee)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints the following arrays:

```
[ 187, 0, 0, 0, 238 ]
[ 187, 1, 1, 1, 238 ]
[ 187, 3, 3, 3, 238 ]
```

However if you need to emit Observables with each data frame then follow the Mark's answer just use `window()` instead of `buffer()`.

Comment: Yes, I need observable for frame, but thanks your answer, this is an option way!