# bufferReduce in RxJS

Tags: javascript, stream, rxjs, reactive-programming

Hello I would like to `bufferReduce` with RxJS and wonder if this is even possible.
The solution function should split a large text into words which characters in total are not longer than 100 chars. The result would look like this:

```
[
  ['lorem ipsum whatever less than 100 chars'],
  ['bla bla blub less than 100 chars'],
]
```

My solution in plain js would be:

```
const calcCharsInWordList = wordList => {
  return wordList.reduce((letterCount, lineWord) => letterCount + lineWord.length, 0) + wordList.length - 1 // add wordlist Length for the sparating spaces
};


const textToLines = (text, maxLineLength) => {
  return text
    .split(' ')
    .reduce((acc, word) => {
      acc.currentLine.push(word);
      if (calcCharsInWordList(acc.currentLine) > maxLineLength) {
        acc.allLines.push(acc.currentLine);
        acc.currentLine = [];
      }
      return acc;
    }, { currentLine: [], allLines: [] })
    .allLines
    .map(line => line.join(' '));
};


console.log(textToLines(`lorem ipsum ....... `, 100));
```

But I want to solve it with RxJS if possible like this:

```
Rx.Observable.from("abc defg hij ...").bufferReduce((acc, letter) => {
   acc = acc.push(letter)
   if(acc.length < 100){ 
     return true; // flush the buffer (I know it should return the acc ;) I just want you to get the idea.)
   }
   return false
})
```

So maybe a nested Observable could help here ? BufferWhen and bufferCount really don't help here. 
I am really excited to solve it with RxJS.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a similar question multiple times here on SO. The basic problem is that operators such as `bufferWhen` or `windowWhen` that call a user function every time they open a new buffer/window don't let you react to values going through. If they did it would make things much easier.

This solution uses `scan` and includes also the last line that can be shorter than the `LIMIT` constant. It's still pretty simple and doesn't involve any `async` schedulers the would be probably necessary when using eg. `ConnectableObservable` (sharing the source Observable and conditionally feeding it into `buffer()`).

```
const input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non lacinia dui. Pellentesque ullamcorper sed enim et rhoncus. Vestibulum iaculis enim eget consectetur sagittis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur mus.';
const LIMIT = 25;

Observable.of(input)
  .concatMap(str => str) // Emit each character separately
  .scan((line, char) => {
    if (line[line.length -1] === "\n") { // The previous line finished, start new line
      return char;
    } else if (line.length > LIMIT && char === ' ') { // Mark the line as finished with "\n"
      return line + "\n";
    }
    return line + char; // Nothing special, just append the char
  }, '')
  // This is required to include the last line that can be shorter than 100 chars.
  // The `subject` just passes everything through until the source completes.
  // Then it uses `concat` to append itself and replays the last value that is terminated with "\n"
  .multicast(new ReplaySubject(1),
    subject => subject.concat(subject.map(line => line + "\n"))
  )
  // Pass through only finished lines
  .filter(line => line[line.length -1] === "\n")
  // Remove the terminating character
  .map(line => line.trim())
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo: http://jsbin.com/fotiluk/13/edit?js,console

This code prints the following output:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
"consectetur adipiscing elit."
"Sed non lacinia dui. Pellentesque"
"ullamcorper sed enim et rhoncus."
"Vestibulum iaculis enim eget"
"consectetur sagittis. Orci"
"varius natoque penatibus et"
"magnis dis parturient montes,"
"nascetur mus."
```

I believe there could be a little shorter solution but I wanted to always emit a simple string from `scan`. If I passed some object I could make it easier to detect when I want to split the line.

Here's a similar question: [How to split a data frame from an arrayBuffer with RxJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203858/how-to-split-a-data-frame-from-an-arraybuffer-with-rxjs/45211881#45211881)

Comment: the scan accumulates the whole input text again and adds \n . Thats actually not what I wanted. I thought its possible to pipe the string like a stream completely.

Comment: The `\n` is not in the result